# Continuous function at range

Tags: calculus

I'm struggling quite a lot while doing the following calculus exercise:

**Given that** $f(x)$ is continuous at $[0,1]$ and $f(0) = f(1)$

**Prove**: If $f(x) = f(x^2)$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ then $f$ is a constant function at $[0, 1]$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to math.se. What have you tried so far?

Comment: As written, this problem is false. Perhaps you mean "If, for all $x$, $f(x)=f(x^2)$, then $f$ is a constant function"?

Comment: According to the definition of continuity, there must exist a series convergent to any point in $[0, 1]$. I can define a series at $[0,1]$, lets say Xn. I must be able to find a sub-series, according to Bolzano Weierstrass that converge to any specific point at that range, Now I'm wondering how it helps me :)

Comment: for any x means for some x or for all x ?

Comment: otherwise look at $f(x) = x(1-x)(1-2x)(1-4x)$ where $f(1/2) = f(1/4) = 0$

Comment: I meant "for all". Fixing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=m$ $f(y)=M$, $M$ the maximum, $m$ the minimum, the sequences $(x^{2n})$ and $(y^{2n})$ converges towards $0$ or $1$ since $f(x^{2^n})=f(x)=m$ and $f(y^{2^n})=f(y)=M$ by continuity we have $f(lim(x^{2^n})=m$ and $f(lim(y^{2^n})=M$ this implies $m=M$ since $f(0)=f(1)$.

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much :)

Comment: @Tsemo Aristide: I think you should have $f(x^{2^n})=f(x)$, not $f(x^{2n})$,  and similarly for $y$.

Answer (score 2):

For any $x_0 \in (0,1)$ construct a sequence $x_n=x_{n-1}^2$ for $n\ge 1$. Then sequence $f(x_n)$ is constant, and $x_n\to 0$, and by continuity $f(x_n)\to f(0)$. But since the sequence is constant then $f(x_0)=f(0)$

Comment: Thank you!, your help is appreciated!